# how to change height of row in tableview ipad dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

hi I am new to iPad developing. So I am using web service to display data in tableview. So how can I change the row heigh of each cell I tried but it showing more height for that one? 
I used three arrays for displaying data in tableview So if I give more data to array through web Service. So how can I change for every row for table view. Can anyone help me ?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [arrOutline1 count] + [arrOutline2 count];           
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    if ((indexPath.row)%2==0) {
        return 100;         
    }
    else {          
         //strData3 =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        NSLog(@" the data is %@",[arrOutline3 objectAtIndex:countRow]);

        //strData3 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrOutline3 objectAtIndex:countRow]];
      int myLength = [[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrOutline3 objectAtIndex:countRow]] length]; 
        NSLog(@" the length of dat is :%d",myLength);

        int LengthCell;
            int LengthCell = myLength /3;
            CGFloat heightCell3 ;
        int l = LengthCell * 19;
        heightCell3 =(CGFloat )l;
        NSLog(@" the heigh of cell is :%f",heightCell3 );
        countRow = countRow + 1;
        return heightCell3;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        if ((indexPath.row)%2==0) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            txtlable1= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, W, H)]; 
            txtlable1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            txtlable1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:25.0];
            txtlable1.text =[arrOutline1 objectAtIndex:count2];
            txtlable1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            txtlable1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            txtlable1.numberOfLines = 0;
            [[cell contentView]addSubview:txtlable1];
            [txtlable1 release];            

        txtlable2= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(600, 0, W-200, H)]; 
            txtlable2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            txtlable2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0];
            txtlable2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            txtlable2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            txtlable2.numberOfLines = 0;
            txtlable2.text =[arrOutline2 objectAtIndex:count2];
            [[cell contentView]addSubview:txtlable2];
            count2 =count2+1;
            [txtlable2 release];
            return cell;

        }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        int myLength = [[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrOutline3 objectAtIndex:count1]] length]; 
        NSLog(@" the length of dat is :%d",myLength);
        int LengthCell = myLength /3;
        CGFloat heightCell3 ;
        int l = LengthCell * 15;
        heightCell3 =(CGFloat )l;
        NSLog(@" the heigh of cell is :%f",heightCell3 );

        txtlable3=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0,W+400,heightCell3)];  
        txtlable3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        txtlable3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:30.0];
        txtlable3.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        txtlable3.numberOfLines = 0;

        txtlable3.text =[arrOutline3 objectAtIndex:count1];
        [cell addSubview:txtlable3];
        count1 = count1 + 1;

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrOutline1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main. candidate of things  thisisingamaldaj",@"Amith",@"Gupta",@"RightData",@"RightData1",@"RightData2",@"RightData3",@"RightData4",@"RightData5",@"RightData6",nil];
    arrOutline2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ganesh",@"surya",@"sudha",@"LeftData",@"LeftData1",@"LeftData2",@"LeftData3",@"LeftData4",@"LeftData5",@"LeftData6",nil];
    arrOutline3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main.\n candidate of things  thisisingamaldaj .\n ",@"jagadish",@"night fhdfhda fhadfhadf.\n dfafhdjkahfa",@"3rdData",@"3rdData1 .\n vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main.\n candidate of things  thisisingamaldaj",@"3rdData2",@"3rdData3",@"3rdData4",@"3rdData5",@"3rdData6 3rdData1 .\n vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main.3rdData1 .\n vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main.3rdData1 .\n vijay sankar ramamknkakjdkl.\n the thinking the main.",nil];

    CGFloat heihtTable;
    heihtTable =[arrOutline1 count] + [arrOutline3 count] ;
    heihtTable =heihtTable *175 ;
    scrl.contentSize=CGSizeMake(728,heihtTable);
    count1=0;
    count2=0;
    countRow =0;
        lblCompetency = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 400, 100)];
    lblCompetency.text = @"Competency";
    lblCompetency.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 24.0];
    [self.scrl addSubview:lblCompetency];

    NSLog(@"The height is %f",heihtTable);
    TableOutline = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 150,1000,heihtTable) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    TableOutline.separatorColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    TableOutline.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [TableOutline setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    TableOutline.opaque=YES;
    TableOutline.delegate =self;
    TableOutline.dataSource = self;
    TableOutline.allowsSelection=FALSE;

    UIView *viewTable2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 1000, heihtTable)];
    viewTable2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    TableOutline.backgroundView =viewTable2;
    [self.scrl addSubview:TableOutline];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);
    NSString *strTemp = [arrServices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([strTemp length] > 0)
        labelSize = [strTemp sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return (labelSize.height + 10);
}
```

This is what I used in my project and it worked perfectly well. Change the values according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try out the delegate method:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And specify the height of the cell parameter based on indexpath.

Comment: k Thanks , but i need to decide the heigh of each cell based on data length.

Comment: @Praveen this is not the place to change height

Comment: @Srikar: Discussion
A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Comment: yes, some basic display properties can be changed here. You could change the height too but you have a separate delegate for it. Why dont you use that?

Answer (score 2):

You can change `UITableViewCell` height in this delegate -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ }
```

For this to work, you could dynamically figure out the content height on the fly or have some predefined heights 100,150,200 etc. & based on some cutoff on your data, use one of these heights... Will reduce complexity.

Otherwise you might want to find the length

---